# MOSFET H-Bridge with PWM for motor control - will this circuit work?

Tags: mosfet, pwm, h-bridge

[image]

I designed an H-Bridge circuit that I will use to drive a 12V wiper motor that can draw 6A. Will this work? Should I just use relays? I want to be able to control speed as well. I will be controlling the PWM and the switching through an Arduino.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is so easily proven by using a sim tool like LTSpice (free of course), gives you a more exact functional and performance evaluation, allows you to tweak values and gives you better peace of mind compared to getting a relatively inexact answer from a bunch of people. Plus it will be the best investment in your time you will likely make in the field of EE.

Answer (score 1):

We can't say whether this will "work" because you haven't specified the desired operation, what controls parts like the two switches, where the tops of D2 and D3 are connected, etc.  In short, this is a documentation mess.

There are also some obvious problems.  There is nothing limiting current when Q3 is on, and Q9 is turned on by "PWM", just to name one.

Step back, create a proper spec for what you want a circuit to accomplish, how it will be controlled, etc, then maybe ask about details of various parts.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work with PWM, because when BJT will cut off, gate capacitance with resistors will not shut the MOSFET fast enough. Use gate driver instead all this complicated stuff around the bridge.

Comment: Any recommendation for a gate driver?

Comment: Personally i like silabs very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the circuit with a few caveats:
1. As @Gregory Kornblum has pointed out, a little more gate drive current might be beneficial to discharge the gates on Q1 and Q3.  Otherwise you will have to keep the PWM frequency pretty low.
2. Assuming only one switch is on at a time for motor direction, it would still be nice to add some type of current sense circuitry, because if the motor stalls you will be driving the motor winding resistance only.  You can use the PWM to limit motor current, but you need to sense it somewhere.  12v Batteries can produce 100's of amperes.
3. You will need a heat sink at 6 amps for the FETS.  For instance, Q2 has an on resistance of 0.3 ohms so at 6 amps you are more than 10 Watts, and RDS(on) increases with temperature.  Since the Junction-to-ambient temperature rise is 62C per watt, you will overheat and blow them right away.
Good luck!